# How to load package to openwrt in virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, fedora, scp, openwrt

I have created an image of OpenWRT(x86-64) which I am running on Virtualbox. I have created a custom package and build it for my Virtual Machine. The thing is that I can not figure out how to copy the package file to the virtual machine's disk space.

I tried using using Guest Additions for Virtualbox but I think OpenWRT does not support it because I can not mount the file to install Guest Additions.

Is there any other way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, you can use Secure Copy (scp) to transfer your files.

Here is the link. [SCP Example](https://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

SCP uses ssh to transfer files. Make sure that you have root password enabled in your remote host as this is needed to make a connection.

I hope that this may help someone in the future.